# Derivation of the equations for ellipse and ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Could someone perhaps explain / prove / guide to a source where I can find the derivations of the general equations of ellipse and ellipsoid? I'm trying to understand where these formulas come from:

$$\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

and

$$(\textbf{x}-\textbf{v})^TA^{-1}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{v}) = 1$$

So my question is: "Why these formulas are the way they are?" Proof? Intuition? :)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: See Wikipedia's ["Proofs involving the ellipse" entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_ellipse) ... which only has one proof, but it's the derivation of the standard form of the ellipse equation. The general ellipsoid lacks the concept of foci, so it's better just to think of it as a sphere that's been stretched by various factors in mutually-perpendicular directions.

Comment: @Blue thank you for your help! :) I would like to see a similar proof for ellipsoid ;)

Comment: If you slice a 3D ellipsoid along the coordinate planes (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid)), you get three ellipses, whose shapes can be independent of each other. That is, the foci that define one slice have nothing to do with the foci that determine another; they don't even have to lie on the same coordinate axes. As a result, the ellipsoid eqn doesn't have a derivation comparable to that of the ellipse. It comes from the unit sphere eqn, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$: the sphere stretched by factors $a$, $b$, $c$ in the coordinate directions has equation $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2=1$.

Comment: @Blue thank you again :)

Comment: @Blue your Wikipedia link above is no longer working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the ellipsoid, just consider the following linear algebra facts.

- Symmetric matrices and quadratic forms

  Let $A$ be a symmetric real $n\times n$ matrix; then its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are real and there exists a set of orthonormal eigenvectors $q_i$ of $A$. We summarize these facts in  matrix form:

$$Q^{t}AQ=\Lambda, $$

or

$$A=Q\Lambda Q^{t}, $$

denoting by $Q$ the orthogonal matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$ and by $\Lambda$ the diagonal matrix s.t. $\Lambda_{ii}=\lambda_i$. In other words, any real symmetric matrix can be diagonalized.
Now, if the eigenvalues are ordered as follows $\lambda_i\geq \dots\geq \lambda_n$, then

$$x^{t}Ax=x^{t}(Q\Lambda Q^{t})x=(Q^{t}x)\Lambda(Q^{t}x)=(\Lambda~\text{is diagonal})=\sum_{i}=(Q^{t}x)_i \lambda_i (Q^{t}x)_i=\sum_{i}\lambda_i ((Q^{t}x)_i)^2 \leq \lambda_1\|x\|^2.$$

We say that $A$ is positive definite if $x^{t}Ax>0$, for all $x$. This is equivalent to state that all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive.

- Ellipsoid

Let $A$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix with real entries. The ellipsoid $\mathcal E_A$ centered at $0$ is the locus

$$\{x: x^{t}Ax\leq 1 \}. $$

The semi axes are defined as the vectors

$$s_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}q_i.$$

i.e. the direction of the semi axes are determined by the eigenvectors of $A$, while the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ determine the "width" of the ellipsoid along the axes.

- Easy example

To see the geometry of the ellipsoid definition, let us consider the case $A=diag\{\frac{1}{a^2},\frac{1}{b^2},\frac{1}{c^2} \}$ with $a,b,c>0$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are its diagonal entries. A basis of orthonormal eigenvectors is given by the standard basis $\{e_i\}$ in $\mathbb R^3$ with $e_1=(1,0,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0)$ and $e_3=(0,0,1)$. Then $Q=Q^t$ and

$$x^{t}Ax=\sum_{i}\lambda_i ((Q^{t}x)_i)^2=\sum_{i}\lambda_i (x_i)^2=
\frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}+\frac{x_3^2}{c^2}$$

for all $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in $\mathbb R^3$.
The ellipsoid $\mathcal E_A$ is the locus

$$\{x\in\mathbb R^3: \frac{x_1^2}{a^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{b^2}+\frac{x_3^2}{c^2}\leq 1 \}. $$

The semi axes are (following the above definition)

$$s_1=a(1,0,0), s_2=b(0,1,0), s_3=c(0,0,1).$$

This is coherent with the geometric interpretation of the semi axes in both the 2 and 3-dimensional cases.

- And now?

You could produce more complicated examples of ellipsoids by considering non trivial positive definite symm. matrices $A$ and considering ellipsoids not centered at $0$. In this case the definition of the locus is already given in your question.

Comment: What if geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue less than algebraic?